# How to send specific webinar links to event registrant based on events selected, with scheduled reminders?

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, scheduled-reminders

We have a weekend event with eight webinar sessions with registration costs. People can register for individual sessions, for all sessions with a discount or for whichever set of sessions they would like. I'd like to be able to send them a set of links for the particular sessions they have registered for. How can I make this happen?

I'm guessing webform is part of the solution and that's fine. I could see some kind of system with key/value pairs for each selection and an option that selects all the sessions if you choose the discounted weekend pass. That would get me the registration confirmation email, but I'm not sure how to get a scheduled reminder with this same information in it. All I can think of is to change the email and use re-send emails for each registrant, but that would be a real pain to click through to each to re-send emails one by one. Also, I'd like to allow people to register additional participants, so each participant would need to get an email instead of just the person who registered them.

Is there a solution that allows customizable scheduled reminder content based on registration details? This would be great for many events, not just webinars.

Comment: i can't see how you can do this if your goal is to send a single scheduled reminder email to registrant listing all the events they registered for, other than doing them as a single event, with each session being a price set option, ie treat this as one event, not eight.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I'm definitely planning to make this one event with price set options. The challenge is sending the email that is customized with the right links for the particular registrant.

Comment: ok. it wasn't obvious to me you were doing this as one event, versus a number of events. both would be do-able via webform. glad you clarified